# Получение из D9 D6 34 01 (hex) числа 10258209 (dec)

Tags: c#, hex

Известен участок кода из C#:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(pathIn, FileMode.Open); // открываем файл
BinaryReader stream_ = new BinaryReader(file);
Debug.WriteLine(stream_.ReadInt32(); // Вывод: 10258209
```

Если короче: я считываю первые 4 байта из файла и должен получить из этого число, соответствующее размеру данного файла

Заглянул я в редактор hex кода и вижу: D9 D6 34 01. Есть ощущение, что всё завязано на системе счисления и переводах в духе бит-байт. Нужен ваш совет)

Comment: подозреваю что вы читаете из файла что то другое. Ибо 10258209 никак не может быть D9 D6 34 01

Comment: Я перечитал мануалы по некоторым функциям и вы скорее всего правы. Пояснение на языке C:4-байтовое целое число со знаком, считанное из текущего потока.
В то же время я смотрю на hex и перевожу уже его в символы согласно таблице ASCII. Скорее всего мой подход неверный и мне стоит подходить с другой стороны

Comment: _число, соответствующее размеру данного файла_ - а какое примерно число должно получиться? Вы же должны иметь представление о возможном диапазоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен: ответ был в самом вопросе. Мне нужно было только получить ascii код каждого символа (4 шт. т.к. нужно было 4 байта), а затем при помощи математических формул преобразовать массив из полученных цифр в 32-битное число.